# RMNET + DM + MODEM mod usb not recognized windows 7 and windows 10

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4, imei

I am trying to change my galaxy gt-i9500 imei. I undertand that I should edit EFS file thanks to my searches. I should connect to usb at RMNET + DM + MODEM mod (*#0808#, choose mod etc.). But windows7/10 machines cannot recognize usb device in this mod.

[image]

Comment: Changing IMEI is illegal in some countries! You should only restore the original phone's IMEI printed on the phone. For Windows not recognizing the phone: Do you have drivers installed?

Comment: Exactly. I am trying to restore original one. Now imei is like something 04XXX.  I have downloaded drivers from samsung formal website. It recognizes at mtp + adb mod.

Comment: What tool are you trying to restore the damaged IMEI with?

Comment: NV-items_reader_writer is my tool

Comment: What is shown in the Windows device manager when the phone is connected to the computer?

Comment: Unknown USB Device (Configuration Descriptor Request Failed)

Comment: Hum... weird. Please can you edit the question providing screenshots?

Comment: I think you are talking about screen shot of computer?

Comment: Well. Try this: dial *#7284# > Qualcomm USB Settings then tell me what's shown there

Comment: It is not opening any window

Comment: What is the phone Android version?

Comment: phone Android version 5.0.1

Comment: The option you have to choose is RNDIS + DM + MODEM. Do you see a such option?

Comment: Yes. I tried it too. But still dont recognize.

Comment: Weird. Im still thinking it's drivers related.

Comment: There is an alternative method by EFS Professional, this one works with ADB (USB debugging). You'll need to give a try.

Comment: I will try and give feedback here

Comment: Root access is a must and install BusyBox as well.